# Can finfo and imagecreatefromjpeg be used as secure method of image uploading in php

Tags: php, file-upload, upload, image-uploading

I have below code for file validation. Can i consider it as secure method for image file uploading in php ?

```
$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
$mime = finfo_file($finfo, $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
if($mime == 'image/jpeg' || $mime == 'image/jpg') {
    $im = @imagecreatefromjpeg($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
    if ($im) {
        // Do the file upload here
    }
}
```

Are there any security threat or risk involved in uploading file of `mime` type `image/jpeg` or `image/jpg` from above function ?